# Python Django Mysql like statement

Tags: python, mysql, django

I constructed a query from a dict like

```
def search(params):
  query_data = []
  db_query = "SELECT * FROM getdata_record_search where "

  for key, value in params.iteritems():
    query_data.append(key + " like " + value + "% and ")
  db_query = re.sub("and\s$", "", db_query + " ".join(query_data))

  query_data = record_search.objects.raw(db_query)
  data = serializers.serialize("json", query_data)
```

I am not seeing an expected output.
When I am doing the same through the manage.py shell, I am seeing the following error.

```
>>> string = 'w3' + '%'
>>> db_query = "SELECT * FROM getdata_record_search where domain like '%s'" % string
>>> db_query
"SELECT * FROM getdata_record_search where domain like 'w3%'"
>>> testdata = record_search.objects.raw(db_query)
>>> testdata
<RawQuerySet: "SELECT * FROM getdata_record_search where domain like 'w3%'">
>>> data = serializers.serialize("json", testdata)
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 122, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 41, in serialize
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1398, in __iter__
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 73, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 87, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, self.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 151, in execute
    query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

What am I doing wrong here?

Upon checking the mysql logs, I cannot see the queries coming there. However, if I am omitting the like statement, and performing just a `select * from getdata_record`, I can see that the query is actually logged in the mysql server.

Comment: Django has a beautiful ORM. Why use Raw Queries when you can do that ? Read up on `Q` objects

Comment: I think the issue is the '%' character. Try to escape it when you construct query by using '/'. And karthikr is right. Why on earch do you need raw sql?

Comment: to address your specific issue, i think it is the case when there are no parameters, you have a dangling `where` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a raw query for anything you're doing here, it's possible via Django ORM:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements

```
def search(params):
    filter_kwargs = {
        '{}__startswith'.format(key): value
        for key, value in params.iteritems()
    }
    query_data = record_search.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", query_data)
```

Comment: Thanks Anentropic, however, if I am using `SELECT * FROM getdata_record_search where domain like 'w3%' and ttl like '3%' `, which has an `and`, will filter_quargs going to work to query on multiple columns?

Comment: yes, if you supply a bunch of kwargs to `filter()` they will be treated as `AND` clauses ....if you needed `OR` logic you'd have to use `Q` objects, but in this case not necessary

Answer (score 1):

With parameterized queries you should be doing:

```
db_query = "SELECT * FROM getdata_record_search where domain like %s"
testdata = record_search.objects.raw(db_query, [some_string])
```